# Use ActionView helper blocks in a rails presenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I'm trying to move some logic out of my views, and I'm using presenters to do so. The affected code is below.

### Presenter:

```
class ApplicationPresenter < ActionView::Base
  extend Forwardable
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end

class ProfilesPresenter < ApplicationPresenter
  def_delegators :@profile, :id

  def initialize(profile, user)
    @profile = profile
    @user = user
  end

  def container(&block)
    path = profile_insights_path(id)
    link_to capture(&block), path
  end
end
```

### The View Partial:

(profile here is a presenter object)

```
<%= content_tag(:li) do %>
  <%= profile.container do %>
    Some Stuff
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to basically use the Presenter Method Like a Helper, so the profile has an 'opinion' about how it behaves. Currently, there isn't any logic in the `container` method, but there will be.
The only problem I am having is the output displays twice:

```
<li>
  Some Stuff
  <a href="/profiles/11725854/insights">Some Stuff</a>
</li>
```

How do I keep the block from firing off the first time?

Answer (score 0):

The direct fix, though not verified, should be removing `capture` from `link_to`, like:

```
link_to &block, path
```

However, even this could be fixed, I think this is a misuse of Presenter. If "Some Stuff" is for view's logic, put it in view. If it is about Profile, why not putting it to present directly? Presenter's job is to those dirty things.

```
class ProfilesPresenter < ApplicationPresenter
  # ....

  def link_for_some_stuff
    path = profile_insights_path(id)
    link_to "Some Stuff", path
  end
end

# View
li
  = profile.link_to_some_stuff
```

Now the view is dumb enough.

If other models need similar method, you can make a parent link method in ApplicationDecorator and inherit it in sub classes.

Comment: I'm pretty new to presenters, so I could well be misusing it, but the goal here is to have the presenter basically decide whether the profile should be represented by an anchor or a div. When I switch to `link_to path, &block` the same issue exists. I've been refactoring, and this needs improvement, but I'm curious as to why it behaves this way (printing twice)

Comment: That's because of `capture`, it will append the output. For presenter, you can also check Draper gem which provides more functionality and easy to use.

Comment: I wasn't able to make this functionality work within the Presenter, but I did double back and move the logic to a helper. I tried moving capture on this, but it didn't change the issue with double rendering. I'm still looking into this, but I haven't had luck with it